# How to run .sh file from android app?

Tags: android, adb

My device has been rooted and now i want to run an `.sh` file from my android application. I tried with following code but it did't provide the intended output:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh /data/local/tmp/xyz.sh");
```

If i run `.sh` file from adb it is working fine for me.

Comment: Grammar and spelling edits, but certainly the author has to add more detail on what is intended and what the error output is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code.

```
     try{
        Process root = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(root.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes("sh /system/bin/xyz.sh \n");
        os.flush();
     }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (SecurityException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This snippet worked for me,I hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh /data/local/tmp/xyz.sh");
Scanner stdout = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
while (stdout.hasNextLine()) {
    Log.i("stdout", stdout.nextLine());
}
stdout.close();
Scanner stderr = new Scanner(process.getErrorStream());
while (stderr.hasNextLine()) {
    Log.e("stderr", stderr.nextLine());
}
stderr.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but this snippet also did't worked ! :-(

Comment: @Newbie what did not work? you need to be more specific.

Comment: .sh file is not getting executed.